# Deployed custom EmailSender SPI in Keycloak results in NullPointerException at runtime

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm currently working on our custom EmailSenderProvider SPI and I get a `NullPointerException` because the provider is not successfully instantiated at run time and returns null. We already have built a custom Federation Provider that works already and are located within the same jar file. I have followed the documentation and have created both the Provider and ProviderFactory classes for the EmailSender and added a new file for provider in /META-INF/services folder. When I deploy the module it can be seen on the Server Info page.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this or make it work?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I can't show the whole content of the project but as a start I only copied the implementation of DefaultEmailSenderProvider and DefaultEmailSenderProviderFactory from Keycloak Github.  I just changed the id of the SPI basically for now. Then I deployed it to check if it works but ran to this problem. So in effect I just added 2 classes CustomEmailSenderProvider and CustomEmailSenderProviderFactory and then created the file org.keycloak.email.EmailSenderProviderFactory with the reference to CustomEmailSenderProviderFactory.

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out what is wrong. Might be a bug but it seems that to make it work, the id for the provider factory still needs to be "default".

Comment: for anyone else who reads this answer, you probably implemented `EventListenerProviderFactory` or some other factory from keycloak. you have to check the return state of your getId method. mine was simply returning null